# How does join() produce different results depending on the arguments?

Tags: javascript, function

I can't quite understand why the join() call below produces different results, depending on the type of argument(s) provided.

Here's what I found:

```js
var test = function() {
  var args = Array.prototype.join.call(arguments,"_");
  return args
};

console.log(test([1,2,3])) // #1: returns 1,2,3
console.log(test(1,2,3)) // #2: returns 1_2_3
```

Given join(arguments, '_'), shouldn't it produce a `_` delimited string in both tests above? Why does #1 return a comma delimited value instead?

Comment: if you tried to `console.log(arguments)` in your `test` function, it'd be clear for you how it's working

Comment: You can also try `test([1,2,3], [4,5,6])`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you pass an array to `test`, the `arguments` object becomes an *array of arrays*, not a plain array of plain values. It's the difference between

```
arguments = [[1,2,3]];
```

and

```
arguments = [1,2,3];
```

When you call `.join` on an array of arrays, each inner array gets implicitly coerced to a string first, resulting in `'1,2,3'` - the values of the inner arrays do *not* get `.join`ed by the delimiter, only the immediate children of the outer array get `.join`ed by the delimiter.

Comment: I didn't know that if the argument was an array, it's wrapped in another array! That makes sense!

Comment: @tkim90 The arguments are *always* wrapped in an array, not just when the argument is an array.

Answer (score 5):

In your code, you only have one argument in the first example, that being an array. Joining a single element will remove the brackets:

```js
var test = function() {
  var args = Array.prototype.join.call(arguments,"_");
  return args
};

console.log(test([1,2,3])) // args = [[1,2,3]]
console.log(test(1,2,3)) // args = [1,2,3]

console.log([[1,2,3]].join('_'))
console.log([1,2,3].join('_'))
```

Another way to look at this is to provide another array as an argument to `test()`:

```js
var test = function() {
  var args = Array.prototype.join.call(arguments,"_");
  return args
};

console.log(test([1,2,3], [4,5,6]))
```

Answer (score 4):

In the first example you are not calling `.join` on the *array* but on `arguments`. That variable will be populated with an array-like object that has an array as first index, in essence, you are calling the equivalent of:

```js
let myArguments = [[1, 2, 3]];

console.log(myArguments.join("_"));
```

instead of what you do (the equivalent of) in the second example:

```js
let myArguments = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(myArguments.join("_"));
```

Answer (score 3):

The first one, first argument is `[1,2,3]` which is joined with the second argument, which is nothing -> output is `[1,2,3].toString()`.

Second call, it's actually joining all the 3 arguments, resulting in outputting `1_2_3`.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're passing one argument which is an array - so it converts it to a string, then attempts to join it to the other arguments (there are none) so it just returns the string.

```js
var test = function() {
  var args = Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, "_");
  return args
};

console.log(test([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(test(1, 2, 3));
```

You can solve this by checking if there's only one argument passed.

```js
var test = function() {
  var args = arguments.length == 1 ? arguments[0].join("_") : Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, "_");
  return args;
};

console.log(test([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(test(1, 2, 3));
```

Answer (score 3):

The result is different, because `arguments` is different.

On the first call (`test([1,2,3])`, you have one argument which is an array.
On the second call, you have 3 arguments, each one being a number.

`Array.prototype.join` is meant to be called over arrays. It will stringify each of the items in the array.

In you your first case, your arguments "array" has only one member, which is an array itself. This argument will be stringfied. An array stringfied becomes exactly what is logged in your code.